# Are the items from /src/test/resources going to jar at Spring Boot Applicaton?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, gradle

Building a Spring Boot Applicaton with gradle ( or maven, believe there are no difference related to the question). Put some files in `/src/test/resources` for test purposes. Do they eventually go to a jar? If yes what is the path to them? Is it different from path to items from `/src/main/resources` (which is like `BOOT-INF/classes` )?

Comment: Nothing from `src/test` goes into a jar file

Comment: A JAR file is just a zipped/compressed file - so one option is to unzip it and inspect its contents for yourself.

Comment: what if I miss something while inspecting? I wanna be 100% sure...

Comment: By definition everything in `src/main/` will be packaged whereas the `src/test` will not being packaged (using for unit tests usually)